# Send pdf in attachment (Laravel Mail)

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code to get some HTML stored in the column "content" of the "badges" table in a pdf:

```
 $pdf = app()->make('dompdf.wrapper');
 $pdf->loadHTML($badgeContent->badge->content);
```

Do you know if is possible to send this pdf in a attachment using Laravel Mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sent almost any file in attachment

in laravel, create a new mailable 
inside build paste this code

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.orders.shipped')
                ->attach('/path/to/file');
}
```

If you need more information on this check laravel's documentation 
(this code is copied from the laravel's documentation 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail#writing-mailables